# How do you reset a counter in Java for multiple inputs?

Tags: java, loops, counter

Hello I am trying to reset a counter in `java`, as I need to print out both the number of factors of a number and the sum of the factors. When I enter multiple integer values, these counters keep adding up. Is there a way in java to reset the counters after each new integer entered? Here is my code so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindFactors {

  public static void main (String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num, factorcounter = 0;
    int sumfactors = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer.");
    while(in.hasNextInt()) {
      num = in.nextInt();
      if(num > 0) {
        for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
          if(num % i == 0) {
            factorcounter++;
            System.out.println(i + " is a factor of " + num);
            sumfactors = sumfactors + i;
          }
        }
        System.out.println("The number of factors: " + factorcounter);
        if (sumfactors / 2 == num) {
          System.out.println(num + " is a perfect number!");
        }
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why are you asking about java? how would you do that in another language? it's the same. just assign the value that you want (e.g. 0) at the point at which you want to reset the variable (e.g. after a new number is read). E.g., `num=0;` sets the value of the counter `num` to 0

Comment: Sorry I asked about Java because I was writing my code in it, I wasn't sure if the method would be the same in other languages. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign zero to your variables.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num,factorcounter = 0;
    int sumfactors = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer.");
    while(in.hasNextInt())
{

        num = in.nextInt();

        factorcounter = 0;
        sumfactors = 0;

        if(num > 0)
        {
            for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
            {
                if(num % i == 0)
                {
                        factorcounter++;
                        System.out.println(i + " is a factor of " + num);
                        sumfactors = sumfactors + i;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("The number of factors: " + factorcounter);
            if (sumfactors/2 == num)
            {
                                System.out.println(num + " is a perfect number!");
            }

        }
        else
        {
                        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!